# Standalone application in C, a good idea?

Tags: c, linux

The term has several definition according to Wikipedia, however what I'm really interested in is creating a program that has all its needed dependencies included within the source folder, so the end user doesn't need to install additional libraries for the app to install. For example, how Mac apps has all its dependencies all within the program itself already...

or is there a function that autotools does this? I'm programming in the Linux environment...

Comment: Use static linking and be done.

Comment: You can probably use autotools to package the libraries you need (probably assuming they use autotools too, which they probably do) with your program, and if you like you can statically link them all together as @İsmail suggests, but why? If they're already installed, the user ends up with two versions taking up space. If not, you can just as easily install them, and simplify the install process for other programs the user installs that use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the source code of your application, or about your application binary?

The answer I'd give for both the cases depends on what libraries you're using.

If you're using libraries that you can find anywhere, that are somehow standard and/or that are quite big, you shouldn't attach them to your application, just require them both to build and to run your application.

Anyway don't be much concerned about your source code: little people will build your application, and they probably know something about programming and how a Linux system works; it won't be a big deal to require many (also not-so-common) dependences to build your application.
For what concerns the binary version it could be a little more problematic, since it will be used by end users who often don't know anything about libraries and programming stuff: you could choose to statically link the smallest and most uncommon libraries to your binary, in order to have less dependences.

Comment: am talking about packaging a program, so that the end user when using doesn't have to worry about dependencies.

Comment: @chutsu: then choose which libraries are common and which are not, and statically link the uncommon ones. Of course you shouldn't statically link your program against Qt/GTK, but you could statically link it against `libSDL_mixer`. Another option is to dynamically link your application against all the libraries, and just ship them with together your program (you'll also need a script to run your application after setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). If some distribution is going to add your application to their repository they'll probably take care of redesign the linking, if needed, so don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it, if you link statically, but it'd be somewhat unusual, and depending on what your program is supposed to do, you might be limiting yourself.

The alternative, if this is not just a one-off project, is to create a Linux Standard Base compatible RPM package and restrict yourself to linking against the libraries and symbols that LSB defines.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ldd` on your program to discover all dependencies, then copy these to your directory, and add a program-wrapper script that issues

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${0##*/}:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" exec "${0##*/}/real-program" "$@";
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating the Mac OS X .app behavior on a plain POSIX system is difficult because it is very hard to guarantee that a process can find it's own executable (there are several way that will *almost* always work...). Mac OS X provides a OS service for this, but Linux (for instance) does not.

Once you've accomplished that feat, this becomes possible. Though, as others have mentioned, it loses the ability to share resource demands (disk space, RAM space, cache space) with other programs that use the same libraries because you'd be using static copies, or dynamically loading your *own* copy from the .app-like bundle.